# Ubuntu images lacking in trial mode

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine

Google Compute Engine [announced on November 4](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.it/2014/11/google-cloud-platform-live-introducing-container-engine-cloud-networking-and-much-more.html) a number of items, [including Ubuntu](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/11/google-cloud-supports-ubuntu?utm_campaign=infoq_content&utm_source=infoq&utm_medium=feed&utm_term=global).

The same post suggests opening a trial account, which I have.  However Ubuntu is not on the list of installable images and the admin console does not allow to manually edit to gcloud compute command.

Is Ubuntu planned for the free trial and if so, when?

Comment: please change yesterday with 04 Nov 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather, Ubuntu is not officially supported by Google. Those images are prepared by Canonical.

You can create instances running Ubuntu during the free trial through their Google Cloud SDK, as [they explain in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems#ubuntu). Here's the command I used

```
gcloud compute --project "your-project-ID" instances create "server-name" --zone "europe-west1-c" --machine-type "n1-standard-2" --network "default" --maintenance-policy "MIGRATE" --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only" --tags "http-server" "https-server" --image "ubuntu-1410-utopic-v20141029" --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud
```

Project with the ID "your-project-ID" needs to exist beforehand. And note the `--image project` flag which allows you to use their Ubuntu images.

BTW If you are using Ubuntu locally, that is on the computer from which you invoke `gcloud`, you can install google-cloud-sdk (this is the exact package name) from Ubuntu partner repository (make sure it's enabled) which is a much nicer experience than Google's recommended `curl whatever | bash`.

Comment: Thanks for the indications; a proper road.  In fact it was the GCE web UI which throws you off.  The natural flow of the site as at present (Nov 2014) direct you to the wizard, but it has a limited set of images listed there.  Via the above link, you get to the alternative method.